# Does this limit exist at every point c

Tags: limits

[image]

Given the function, Does $ \lim_{x \to c} {f(x)}$ exist at every point C in the interval $(-1,2)

I learned that Limit will not exist at a certain point for a function if:

1. Function 'jumps'
2. Function grows too large to have a limit
3. Function oscillates too much to have a limit.

I have trouble understanding these 3. How do I understand better graphically ?

Comment: Look at $\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ for $x$ approaching $+\infty$.

Comment: The first case occurs in the given plot at $x=2$. The function "jumps" from its left-limit $\lim\limits_{x\to2^-}f(x)=0$ to its right-limit $\lim\limits_{x\to2^+}f(x)=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

I try to describe this graphically, without rigorous definitions. In short, if a function $f$ has a limit $L$ at a certain point $c$ of it‘s domain, if we can make the value of $f(x)$ as close as to $L$ as we by taking $x$ sufficiently close to $c$. Please note that therefore, $L$ has to have a single and concrete value. The value of $f(c)$ is irrelevant here, because we are taking $x$ close to, but unequal to, $c$. So, in your diagram, $\lim_{x \to 0}f = -2$, even if $f(0)=-1$.

For the case $c=2$, we have to introduce right- and leftsided limits. That is, $x$ approaches $c$ from the right or left. At $c=2$, the rightsided limit $\lim_{x \to 2+}f = -2$ and the leftsided limit  $\lim_{x \to 2-}f = 0$. Since both are unequal we don‘t have a general limit at this point.

We neither have a limit at $c$ if, as $x$ approaches $c$, $f(x)$ becomes arbitrarily large or small, i.e. goes to positive or negative infinity, since we cannot state a certain limit $L$. This doesn‘t happen in your diagram.

Another possibility for $f$ not having a limit is, if $f$ oscilates infinitely if $x$ approaches $c$. @Lelouch gave an example with $f(x)=\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$. Since $\frac{1}{x}$ becomes arbitrarily large, as $x$ approaches $0$, $\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ assumes  the values of $1$ and $-1$ at infinitely many points closer to $0$. So we cannot make $f(x)$ as close easy we like to a certain value. But this also doesn‘t happen in your diagram.

To understand this better graphically, as you wrote, try to imagine what happens to the value of your $f$, if you take $x$ closer and closer to $c$ and ignore (only for this purpose) the value of $f(c)$. If $f(x)$ approaches a single and concrete value, this is your limit.